# How to change font family dynamically in a functional component?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that fetches a random font from Google Font and pass it down to a functional component to render it.

```
function Palette() {
  const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=${key}`;
  const [font, setFont] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchFont = async url => {
      const res = await axios(url);
      const items = res.data.items;
      const idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length - 1);
      setFont(items[idx].family);
    };

    fetchFont(url);
  }, [url]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Palette</h1>
      <Card fontFamily={font} bgColor="green" color="white">
        {font}
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
}
```

How can I import this font dynamically inside the child component for styling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append the the link tag that loads the font like this

```
const font = null;
const id = 'dynamic-font';

if (document.getElementById(id)) {
  font = document.getElementById(id);
} else {
  font = document.createElement('link');
  font.rel='stylesheet'
  font.id = id
  document.head.appendChild(font)
}

font.href = // url to the font;
```

Then you can use the font in your CSS.

Another solution would be to actually download the .ttf / .otf files, then write the appropriate @font-face css class, create a CSS class that has the font-family set to the created font-face and apply the class to the desired element.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
<Card style={{fontFamily: font, backgroundColor: 'green', color: 'white'}}>
   {font}
</Card>
```

You can just set inline-css style in react like above. :)

Comment: fontFamily: 'font' -> can this font variable locate a URL resource ? For instance something like this: fontFamily: `${http://myApp/app/files/font/123.tff}` - A custom font file that I store on my DB. Uploaded and fetched by users (sort of a font manager)